# How can we create Custom keyboard app & Keyboard Themes with flutter? - Android & IOS

Tags: android, flutter, keyboard, mobile-application

How can we create Custom keyboard app & Keyboard Themes with flutter for Android & IOS? (English Language Keyboard). Is there any package or **Source code** I can use to build this custom keyboard app? Highly appreciate your support explanation with source code or package.

Appreciate if you can explain with either Source code or package use to build this.